# How to convert (number with % sign) to (round(number) with % sign)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rounding, decimal-point

df is as follows

```
    col1        col2
    10.56%      a
    55.78%      b
    700%        c
    118.13%     d
    200%        e
    102%        f
    45.25%      g
    67.765%     h
```

i want df['col1'] like below(rounded off to 0 decimal with '%' sign):

col1
    11%
    56%
    700%
    118%
    200%
    102%
    45%
    68%

My code is not working properly for some entries

```
df['col1'] = [re.sub("%","",str(x)) for x in list(df['col1'])]
df['col1'] = df['col1'].map(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='ignore'))
df = df.round({'col1': 0})
df['col1'] = [re.sub(".0","%",str(x)) for x in list(df['col1'])]
```

Like 700% changes to 7%

118.13 to %%

some to %6%

and for some entries it is working fine.

Please help me with this!!!

Comment: Just about every line of your code defeats the point of pandas. Doesn't `df['col1'] = df['col1'].astype(int)` do what you are looking for once you strip away the `%`?

Comment: @roganjosh This gives ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '10.56'. Also for me challenge is adding % again after removing it

Comment: Yep, I posted an answer and, in doing so, found it wasn't quite as trivial as I first thought since you have to change types quite a few times :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and dirty way:

```
import pandas as pd

perc_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'col1' : ['65.94%', '761.19%', '17281.0191%', '9.4%', '14%'],
     'col2' : ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
})


perc_df['col1'] = pd.to_numeric(perc_df['col1'].str.replace('%', ''))
perc_df['col1'] = pd.Series([round(val, 2) for val in perc_df['col1']], index = perc_df.index)
perc_df['col1'] = pd.Series(["{0:.0f}%".format(val) for val in perc_df['col1']], index = perc_df.index)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can using `to_numeric` after `strip` the '%'

```
pd.to_numeric(df.col1.str.strip('%')).round(0).astype(int).astype(str)+'%'
0     11%
1     56%
2    700%
3    118%
4    200%
5    102%
6     45%
7     68%
Name: col1, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': ['10.2%', '5.3%', '79.6%']})

df['b'] = df['b'].str.strip('%').astype(float).round(0).astype(int).astype(str) + '%'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would define a function so I can loop it with apply():

```
def change(row, col):
    target = row[col]
    number = float(target.replace("%",""))
    number = round(number,0)
    return "{}%".format(int(number))

df["col1"] = df.apply(change, col = "col1", axis = 1)
```

Comment: `apply` is not vectorized. It will run at the same speed as calling a function on list elements.

Comment: You're right @roganjosh, I will edit my answer to avoid misleading anyone.

Comment: This approach is going to be slower than other options presented

Comment: @Chris to be fair, it may be faster than [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53436848/4799172) which is also throwing in list comprehensions and calling the `Series` constructor multiple times